# "This property must be an Array, not an array" Error from AWS Healthlake

Tags: amazon-web-services, hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I'm converting Apple records data (in DSTU2 format) to R4 format.

This is the data I'm sending to healthlake server

```
{
  "category": [
    {
      "text": "Vital Signs",
      "coding": [
        {
          "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/observation-category",
          "code": "vital-signs"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "issued": "2017-03-18T00:00:00Z",
  "status": "final",
  "id": "49a1b0f9-34c2-472d-8b64-34447d307c56",
  "code": {
    "text": "Temperature",
    "coding": [{ "system": "http://loinc.org", "code": "8310-5" }]
  },
  "encounter": { "reference": "Encounter/355" },
  "subject": { "reference": "Patient/82146c45-a7cd-47ee-a5ba-8c588d4c5c9e" },
  "valueQuantity": {
    "code": "Cel",
    "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
    "value": 37.6,
    "unit": "Cel"
  },
  "resourceType": "Observation",
  "meta": { "lastUpdated": "2023-01-30T09:17:54.772Z" }
}
```

But the healthlake server is giving me the following error

```
{"resourceType":"OperationOutcome","issue":[{"severity":"error","code":"processing","diagnostics":"This property must be an Array, not an array","location":["Observation.category[0]"]}]}
```

What does this error means and how to fix this?

PS: I'd only googled the error and could not get any leads

Answer (score 0):

So I ran your query against my Healthlake instance and it worked great. Can you supply more details about the way your Create API call looks like?